# When I use CoreData, I got an error : [NSAsynchronousFetchResult count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My codes are as follows:

```
- (void)didClickSave {
if([_addView.name.text isEqualToString:@""]||[_addView.time.text isEqualToString:@""]||[_addView.number.text isEqualToString:@""]||[_addView.country.text isEqualToString:@""]||[_addView.intro.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    UIAlertController *omitAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"message omit" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [omitAlert addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:omitAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    Animation *animation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Animation" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext];
    animation.name = _addView.name.text;
    animation.time = _addView.time.text;
    animation.number = _addView.number.text;
    animation.country = _addView.country.text;
    animation.intro = _addView.intro.text;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_addView.imageView.image);
    animation.image = imageData;
    animation.like = _addView.like.on;
    [appDelegate saveContext];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Error:

> 2017-11-09 17:50:34.492561+0800 Animation[3807:1835973]
>   -[NSAsynchronousFetchResult count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c8087670 2017-11-09 17:50:34.495239+0800
>   Animation[3807:1835973] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSAsynchronousFetchResult
>   count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c8087670'

Codes with fetchRequestWithEntityName: called are as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)animationArr {
if(_animationArr == nil) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Animation"];
        NSError *error = nil;
        _animationArr = [appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:request error:&error];
    }
    return _animationArr;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.animationArr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    self.animation = [self.animationArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellName.text = self.animation.name;
    return cell;
}
```

I have checked many times but I cannot find the mistakes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be related to that code.

Comment: Yes...I cannot find any codes related to NSAsynchronousFetchResult. Is it related to FetchRequest?

Comment: @LeeG4ng The name suggest that, I guess that `NSAsynchronousFetchResult` is just the name of internal iOS SDK class. Where do you fetch?

Comment: @Larme I have added the codes with etchRequestWithEntityName: method. But when I don't call this method, I got the error as well.

Comment: you are using an object of NSAsynchronousFetchResult instead of NSArray or NSMutablearray to get count of item your app crashes at animationArr.count check animationArr datatype is correct its an array or not

Comment: @NitinGohel But I didn't declare any object of NSAsynchronousFetchResult .

Comment: you did not declare but the array filled out by other datatype check the [appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:request error:&error];
    } its return NSArray or not

Comment: TAKE A LOOK : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-asynchronous-fetching--cms-22241

Comment: Your code is using `executeRequest`, it should be using `executeFetchRequest`.

Comment: @pbasdf Yes! I changed it. It works. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

For the fatch data your code required to following method and passing:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Animation"];

NSAsynchronousFetchRequest *asynchronousFetchRequest = [[NSAsynchronousFetchRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest completionBlock:^(NSAsynchronousFetchResult *result) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Process Asynchronous Fetch Result
            [weakSelf processAsynchronousFetchResult:result];
        });
    }];
```

For disply:

```
- (void)processAsynchronousFetchResult:(NSAsynchronousFetchResult *)asynchronousFetchResult {
    if (asynchronousFetchResult.finalResult) {
        // Update Items
        [self yourarray:asynchronousFetchResult.finalResult];

        // Reload Table View
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

For More details check a reference link : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-asynchronous-fetching--cms-22241

Comment: I solved the question just now by changing executeRequest into executeFetchRequest. Thanks anyway!!